# Angular Internationalization link sharing

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, internationalization, amazon-cloudfront, angular-i18n

We have different angular i18n builds for many language.
As I understand the standard way of doing things is having different base-href like `/es`, `/en`, `/fr`, etc.
However we would like to have the same links for different languages.

We are using an s3 bucket with cloudfront for the english version at the moment. I proposed to have a language [header and redirect with a lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/) but we aren't sure that will work as intended.

Is there an accepted way to do this ? It seems like a basic use case.

Comment: Any luck in your quest? I am happy even with the "/en"-style base-href, but I struggle to find a good tutorial for a aws-newbie like me ...